# Android AsyncTask Dialog Alert

Tags: android, exception, android-asynctask, looper

I have a splash screen which check an URL if there's any new content on the server. If show i wish to show a AlertDialog, to the app user so that depending on the action of user,i.e if YES download new contents from the server and get it to database else if NO load the contents for the app from the server.

However i am not being able to use an alert dialog inside AsyncTask
My snippet code is as:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... mode){
  /* I AM QUERY MY DATABASE FOR THE PREVIOUS CONTENT(SAY CONTENT 1, CONTENT 2);
  * then i start my connection to the server which has an xml file with the content
  * info (say content 3), at this stage .
  * i Check certain condition here,
  * say if result ==0 then i wish to display an alertdialog.
  * I used an alert dialog and i get some error. Stating use Looper or Handler.

  * Can anyone help me with this?
  */  
}
```

**Edited**

So in

```
doInBackGround(String... mode){
  if(result==0){
    // how do i implement this alert show that if the dialog appears and on clicking Yes i wish to exectute the URL handling part below        

    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    alert.setTitle("Updates Found");
    alert.setMessage( "New Updates for has been found.\n Would you like to download ?\n"
              + "Whats the update: Checking "+pld.result.get(i).get( "issue" ));
    alert.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);                              
    alert.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes,
      new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) { 
          try { 
            URL url = new URL(pld.result.get(i).get("link"));
            ManageZipFile.getArchive(url,pld.result.get(i).get("issue"), file); 
          } 
          catch (Exception ex) { 
            Log.d(TAG, "Exception from URL"+ ex.getMessage()); 
          }

          progressState += updateProgressBar(20);
          pld.saveCoverData(pld.result.get(i).get("issue"));
          try { 
            pldContent = new PullLoadData(getString(R.string.files_path) 
                                          + pld.result.get(i).get("issue") 
                                          + "/contents.xml",context); 
            pldContent.getNewsItems();
            progressState += updateProgressBar(20); 
          } 
          catch(XmlPullParserException e) { 
            Log.e(TAG, "GetNEWSITEM "+ e.getMessage()); 
          } 
          catch (IOException e) { 
            Log.e(TAG, "XML FIle not found" + e.getMessage()); 
          } 
        } 
     });

     alert.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, 
       new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) { 
           dialog.dismiss();
       }
     }); 

     AlertDialog showAlert = alert.create();
     showAlert.show();
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UI thread means it is associated directly with your UI.you cant do operations like *network datafetch,disk access etc* which require large processing time in your UI thread. They should be done in seperate thread.

`AsyncTask` helps to carry out theese operations in seperate thread which may otherwise results in infamous ANR error.(application not responding).

AsyncTask contain methods like `onPreExecute() onPostExecute() onProgressUpdate() ,doInBackground ()`etc you can access UI thread from `onPreExecute() onPostExecute() onProgressUpdate()` .The operation requiring longer processing time should be carried out in `doinbackground().`

I can't understand the functionality demands from your question but if you want to display `Alert Dialog` **before** data fetching operation,**Display it from onPreExecute()**
or if you want to display **after** data fetch **Do it from onPostExecute().**

Comment: Thanks i did understand what you said and what i read? as inDobackGround i am not being able to start my AlertDialog. can you pls sneak into it

Comment: when a condition is true, say if(result==0){then only i need an AlertDialog which i have created on protected void onPreExecute() and on my dialog i have two buttons, OK CANCEL on OK, i need to run a URL CONNECTIOn}

Comment: if your condition is true then display alertdialog.if response is ok execute asynctask.is that what you needed?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html find the above link and try reading about asynctask ..

Comment: Exceptional, now i got it what you meant. Thanks you mate.

Comment: +1 for the nice answer and comments!(Not Just Because your display name) :D :P

Answer (score 5):

This is because the method `doInBackground` runs on a non-UI thread, and an `AlertDialog` needs to be displayed on the UI-thread.

To solve your problem, move the code for your `AlertDialog` to the method `onProgressUpdate` in `AsyncTask`, then when you want to display the `Dialog` call `publishProgress()` from `doInBackground`

```
protected String doInBackground( String... mode ) {
  if( something )
    //Conditions for showing a Dialog has been met
}

protected void onProgressUpdate( Void... params ) {
  //Show your dialog.
}
```

If you need to pass some kind of variable/data to the dialog, you can pass the kind of data you declared in `extends AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>` - where `Progress` is the type of parameter you can pass via the `publishProgress( myVariable )`-method.

Comment: I edited my question can you please elaborate on it. i am confused with thread, things

Comment: Can you help me out here with my EDit. onPreExecute() i have created a dialog, but the dialog has two button ok and cancel when i click ok, i need to do other stuff such as url connection.